# Issues with javascript className function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building an android app that uses webviews from an existing mobile web app. The existing mobile web app has a header graphic and also a footer navigation that uses unordered lists.

Since the android app has native navigation and a header already built into the app, when using a webview of the pages in the mobile web app, the web app header and footer are redundant in the android app. Since the mobile web app will be used for devices such as blackberrys and windows phones, I cannot universally remove the header and footer. Also, the web app header uses some CSS so I need to make sure that's in there for the mobile web app.

So what I decided to try was use javascript to detect the android OS, dynamically assign a class name to the header and footer divs when it detects the android OS, and reference the class name in CSS to not display these divs. If the OS is not android then it will create the style pointer to the CSS file that is needed for the header in the mobile web app.

I am not a javascript or CSS expert, so I came up with a simple test to make sure this all works. Everything works except it does not seem to be assigning the class name to the div for it to be not displayed when the android OS is detected. I know it's detecting the android OS because I have an alert in the if statement and that works. I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. I tested this on a Google Nexus 7 using android 4.4 and Chrome, and on a Motorola RAZR Droid with android 4.1.2 using Chrome.

The test code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<style>
.android
{
    display:none;
}
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    }
};

var divID = "test";

var newClassName = "android";

function changeClass() {

var divReference = document.getElementById(divID);

divReference.className = newClassName;

};

if( isMobile.Android() ) 
    {
        alert("android!");
        changeClass();

}
else
{
    alert("Not android!");
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='header.css' type='text/css'>");
}

</script>





<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Detect android device and hide second UL list below. If not android device, then hide   the first UL list.</h1>
<div class="notandroid">
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h2>This header is after the first UL list</h2>

<div id="test">
<ul>
<li>four</li>
<li>five</li>
<li>six</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h2>This header is after the second UL list</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move your `<script>` to the very end of the `<body>`.

Comment: or eclosed it in a window.onload?

Comment: Except that the script is also `document.write`-ing a CSS tag, which ideally should still live in the HEAD.  I think it needs to be split up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your script tag at the bottom of the body. The div does not exist at the time that the script is run. Browsers parse and run javascript inside script tags as soon as they encounter it - so you need to run the javascript after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `changeClass()` before the Element you are trying to `document.getElementById()` with is defined. Either put your code in `onload = function(){/*in here*/}`, or put your script tag at the bottom of your body. In short, HTML has to be created before you can get it with JavaScript. Additionally, `document.write()` is not supported in XHTML. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

Comment: For the record, `window` is implicit, so `onload` is the same as `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good reasons for avoiding browser-detection.  But if you're determined to go ahead with this, the main issue you're having is that this code is running in the HEAD, but the DIV you're looking for doesn't exist yet, as it's in the body.  You might have to do this in two blocks, if you want the `document.write` for the CSS in the HEAD.

Comment: Shouldn't use `document.write()` in XHTML. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

Comment: @PHPglue: And there are many good reasons to avoid browser detection, but the OP does both.